# How to judge the animate function complete and show something?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

The code like this:

```
$(".hide").click(function(){
    $(".online-contact").animate({width: 'toggle',height: '100%'}, "fast");         
    $(this).hide();
    $(".show-class").show();
})
```

I want to show the div with the class of show-class when the  the animate function complete,what can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate can take a callback which is a function that will run when the animation is complete, like so:

```
$(".hide").click(function(){ $(".online-contact").animate({width: 'toggle',height: '100%'}, "fast", function() {$(".show-class").show();});
 $(this).hide(); })
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try:

```
$(".hide").click(function() {
    $(".online-contact")
        .animate({
            width: 'toggle',
            height: '100%'
        }, "fast",
        function() {
            // your code goes here..
            // this code will execute after the animation ended
        });
```